# Google Sheets API limitations

Tags: session, google-sheets

Is there any session or query limits for calling google sheet api

url is:

[https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list//1/public/values?alt=json](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/%3CID%3E/1/public/values?alt=json)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question doesn't include a brief description about the search/research done. Please take the [tour], checkout [ask] and add more details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are limits. They may differ based on weather you are using a free or paid account. They also may change at google's whim. The following links are google pages that should stay uptodate and are most relevant to the question.

Apps Script Quotas:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Web API Quotas:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits

Comment: How to display datepiker by double click on specific column using rest API?